# I want to run a stopwatch program in the background of my main program , and print the time at the end of th emain programe

Tags: python

I am new to programming ,and i want to know how to run a stopwatch program in the background without displaying the time constantly and at the end i want it to print how long the user took to go through the program

Comment: oh and the main program is a guessing game where the user tries ot guess the random number the computer choses

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to "run a stopwatch". Simply save off the start time, do your stuff, then calculate the time difference at the end.

```
import time

t0 = time.time()

do_whatever()

elapsed = time.time() - t0
print "That took {0} seconds".format(elapsed)
```

Comment: Thank you , it was really helpful

Comment: You're welcome. Remember, when asking questions, to up-vote any answer that helps, and accept the one that best answers your question.